# Access theme defined with MUI in a styled component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm using MUI's theming capabilities. I have a file `theming.js` that has:

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const myTheme = createTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: '#BD72A8',
        },
        secondary: {
            main: '#00A0BE',
        },
    },
});
```

I'm attempting to create a styled component that draws on the theme's palette. Here's what I have so far:

```
import { withTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const LeftSidebar = withTheme(styled.div`
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.palette.secondary.main};
    border-radius: 4px;
`);

return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
    <LeftSidebar>
        ...
    </LeftSidebar>
    </ThemeProvider>
)
```

The styles component `LeftSidebar` is picking up the other styles I define, but it's not using the secondary color on my palette as defined in `theming.js`. In fact, it looks like it's falling onto a different definition of 'theme', because this code results in the border's color being #f50057 - not the secondary color I chose at all, but also not blank.

Can anybody help me understand what I'm doing wrong in trying to combine MUI and styled components?

Comment: Remove the **withTheme** function and handle only **styled** like `styled('div')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765217/styled-component-in-react-typeerror-cannot-read-property-color-of-undefined), I kept tinkering around and learned that it wasn't working because I was using the `ThemeProvider` from MUI, whereas it works if I use the `ThemeProvider` from styled-components. In other words, this now works:

```
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';

const LeftSidebar = styled.div`
    ...
    border: 2px solid ${props => props.theme.palette.secondary.main};
`;

...

<ThemeProvider theme={mnemoTheme}>

        <LeftSidebar>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**try this** 
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';

interface MyThemeComponentProps {
  color?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  variant?: 'normal' | 'dashed';
}

const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MyThemeComponent: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: 'darkslategray',
        },
        primary: {
          color: 'darkblue',
        },
        secondary: {
          color: 'darkred',
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        },
      },
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'primary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkblue',
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'secondary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkred',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

const MyThemeComponent = styled('div', {
  // Configure which props should be forwarded on DOM
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) =>
    prop !== 'color' && prop !== 'variant' && prop !== 'sx',
  name: 'MyThemeComponent',
  slot: 'Root',
  // We are specifying here how the styleOverrides are being applied based on props
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
    styles.root,
    props.color === 'primary' && styles.primary,
    props.color === 'secondary' && styles.secondary,
  ],
})<MyThemeComponentProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));

export default function UsingOptions() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="primary" variant="dashed">
        Primary
      </MyThemeComponent>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="secondary">
        Secondary
      </MyThemeComponent>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```